# PJSIP giving error when trying to run on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sip, voip, pjsip

I tried to compile the newly released PJSIP 2.4.5 for iOS using this tutorial https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone however I am faced with this error: No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386). I am using Xcode 7.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Target--> Build Settings tab. Then under  Architectures section, set " Build Active Architecture Only " to No.